# Inserting HTML Tags in SQLite (Android App)

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry for my bad English. I'm new to Android App Development and recently I bought a Quiz App (made from Ionic Framework /and uses sqlite) and everything works fine. I uploaded it to my Google Play Developer account for alpha testing.

The only problem I had is inserting html tags on questions for example:

```
What's the <u>result</u> of 5+5? / 
<strong>Google</strong> is an operating system.
```

It does not output exactly the way I wanted it. It still shows the raw text file.

Sample database file can be found here: https://www.mediafire.com/?x0ig3gu7mxohngd

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can display Html formatted text in TextView using following code.

```
String str="<b>Hello</b>";
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```